# Merging variable rows within a selection individually

Tags: vba, excel, automation, excel-2007

I have an Excel 2007 table which looks like this:

```
    /|    A    |    B     |    C     |    D
    -+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    1| Item1   |  Info a  |  1200    | sum(C1:C2) 
    2|         |          |  2130    |          
    3| Item2   |  Info b  |  2100    | sum(C3:C7)
    5|         |          |  11      |          
    6|         |          |  12121   |          
    7|         |          |  123     |          
    8| Item3   |  Info c  |  213     | sum(C8:C10) 
    9|         |          |  233     |          
   10|         |          |  111     |
```

What I hope to do is that whenever I select the entire table (`A1:C10` for the above example) and press `<Ctrl> + <M>`, the macro code will automatically merge the blank cells with the cell above them that contains text e.g. `A1` to `A2`; `A3` to `A7` and so forth. The same goes for column `B`. For column `D`, after merging, it would also sum up all the items in column `C`. I could do the merging and summation manually, however it would take me quite a while so I've been looking into macros to make life easier.

I would like to emphasize that the number of rows to merge on each item is variable (`Item 1` has only 2 rows - `A1` and `A2`, `Item 2` has 4, and so on.)

Is this possible to do in Excel VBA? Any help and comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer: yes it's possible. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yup, I have, but rather than selecting the whole table itself, I tried making a macro that will do what I wanted per row. For example, I would first highlight A1 to D2, then run the macro which will merge A2 to A1, B2 to B1, D2 to D1 and set D1 to sum(C1:C2). However, I've been having a problem with making the range dynamic (The macro will only merge a selection that contains 2 rows, other than that, it won't work properly)

Comment: Allow me to rephrase: please show us what you've tried, else we can't help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of rows, avoid looping through the cells themselves, as this is quite slow.  Instaed copy the cells values to a Variant array first.

```
Option Explicit

Sub zx()
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Dim vSrcData As Variant
    Dim vDestData As Variant
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long, i4 As Long

    Set rngTable = Range("A1:D10")

    vSrcData = rngTable
    ' vSrcData is now a two dimensional array of Variants

    ' set vDestData to an array of the right size to contain results
    ReDim vDestData(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngTable.Columns(1)), _
                    1 To UBound(vSrcData, 2))

    ' keep track of row in Destination Data to store next result
    i3 = LBound(vSrcData, 1)

    ' loop through the Source data
    For i1 = 1 To UBound(vSrcData, 1) - 1
        ' sum the rows with blanks in clumn A
        If vSrcData(i1, 1) <> "" Then
            For i2 = i1 + 1 To UBound(vSrcData, 1)
                If vSrcData(i2, 1) = "" Then
                    vSrcData(i1, 3) = vSrcData(i1, 3) + vSrcData(i2, 3)
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            ' copy the result to Destination array
            For i4 = 1 To UBound(vSrcData, 2)
                vDestData(i3, i4) = vSrcData(i1, i4)
            Next
            i3 = i3 + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' delete original data
    rngTable.ClearContents

    ' Adjust range to the size of results array
    Set rngTable = rngTable.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vDestData, 1), _
                                               UBound(vDestData, 2))

    ' put results in sheet
    rngTable = vDestData
End Sub
```

Set Quick Key from Excel, Tools/Macros menu, Options

Comment: thanks for the reply Chris. However, I humbly ask that you explain the code a bit more since like my name implies, I'm new to coding in VBA. I also do not understand what exactly is a variant array and how does one actually use it...

Comment: @Newbie_Coder: May I suggest that you read up on the basics of VBA before asking for detailed explanations. There are plenty of descriptions of "variant arrays" etc. out there, and there's no need to type one from scratch here. Feel free to ask specific questions about specific problems, though. (i.e. not "please explain the entire code")